# Issue uploading some mp4 with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, file-upload

I have a website where users can upload videos. I have been having an issue with some mp4 not uploading. Specifically ones coming from Android phones. I can get most mp4 upload just fine but the ones form that device are encode in some way that is rejecting them.

Anyone know why this is or a fix for it?

Comment: "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed." Its just not allowing the file type. Its like it doesn't see that mp4 as a mp4

Comment: I already had: 'mp4' => 'video/mp4', to fix the issue I was having I changed it to 'mp4' => array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp'), and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue I was having I changed it to `'mp4'   =>  array('video/mp4', 'video/3gpp'),` and now it works. Not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter doesn't recognize the `mp4` file as valid, since .mp4 isn't part of the default array of acceptable mime types.

Add this entry to your `config/mimes.php`:

```
'mp4'   =>  'video/mp4',
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I already did this. Notice I said that I can get most upload. Its more an issue with the some not being recognized.